# Protractor IE11 random failing tests

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have 45 tests that I run on protractor, when I run on chrome all tests pass, I have angular-typescript app.

when I run on IE11 the whole things become slower and 1-2 random tests fail sometimes and sometimes they all pass.

**helper.ts:**

```
public static clickAndWait(element: ElementFinder): webdriver.promise.Promise<void> {
    return element.click();
    }

public static ElementById(idStr: string ): ElementFinder {
    browser.wait(function() { return ( element( by.id(idStr)).isPresent()); }, 32000);
    return element( by.id(idStr));
}



public static getElementByRepeater(repeater: string): ElementArrayFinder {
    return(element.all(by.repeater(repeater)));
}

public static getElementByRepeaterAndIndex(repeater: string , index : number): ElementFinder {
    browser.wait(function() { return  (element.all(by.repeater(repeater)).get(index)).isPresent(); }, 32000);
    return (element.all(by.repeater(repeater)).get(index));
}

public static getElementByRepeaterLast (repeater: string ): ElementFinder {
    browser.wait(function() { return  (element.all(by.repeater(repeater)).last()).isPresent(); }, 32000);
    return (element.all(by.repeater(repeater)).last());
}
```

The error that I tend to get `Failed: Wait timed out after 32084ms`.

I know that because of timeout of my function but i need a fix.
Should I add protractor expectedConditions ? should i clear the cache/cookies on every test run?.
npm version: `3.10` protractor version: `4.0.9` jasmine version: `2.5.2`.

Thanks.